# Concat two Razor C# @values inside ID of a View's element in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, concatenation

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to achieve it.

I was previously writing something like this:

or

```
<div id="sometext_@i.category"/>
```

and it worked.

However, the need arose to change the way of setting ids, as it does not meet the requirements anymore.

I would like to concat two values, something like this:

```
<div id="@i.category + @i.category2" />
```

however the above does not work. 
I also tried:

```
<div id ="@(i.category + i.category2)" />
```

but it did not work neither.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: `<div id='@$"{i.category}{i.category2}"' />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string.Format for this:

```
<div id="@string.Format("{0}{1}", i.category, i.category2)" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. this seems to be responding to my needs.